# How to do float operation in Shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, floating-point

```
time_value=$(($large / 1000))
```

`$large` could be `60` or `57`. I'm expecting `57/1000=0.057`. But I'm getting `0`. So, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
time_value=$((echo scale=3 ; echo $large / 1000) | bc )
```

where

- `scale=`3 tell bc to use 3 digit after dot/comma
- `echo $large / 1000` just compute division

Please note that, once you set floating point, you have to carry it all over the place.

if `$time_value` above is bellow 0, it cannot be used in usual `$(( ))` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!. and one more thing, it is resulting `.060`. but later in my code im doing like this `flowspersec=$((flows / time_value))` where flows could be the value 29. I'm getting error `syntax error: operand expected (error token is ".060")`

Comment: @Veerendra you cannot force `bc` to add leading zero. Just use other tool like `awk` to make calculation or even shell itself if you are using e.g. `zsh`.

Comment: @jimmij I'm new to shell script. Can you explain how to do with `awk`. That would be very helpful

Comment: @Veerendra `awk '{print $1/1000}' <<<$large`. Use `printf` instead of `print` if you want to format it differently (e.g. round up).

Comment: @jimmij `awk '{printf $1/0.060}' <<<29` that is my intention. It works fine, if I run in shell directly(`awk '{printf $1/0.060}' <<<$test` where `test=29` also works fine ). But  not `awk '{printf $1/$test2}' <<<29` where `test2=0.060`

Comment: @Veerendra Inside `awk` shell variable are not available, you need to pass them to `awk` with -v option: `awk -vT=$test2 '{printf $1/T}' <<<29` or `awk '{printf $1/$2}' <<<"29 $test2"` - here `$1` stores first value, and `$2` second.